# AttributeError: accessing private attribute '_max_episode_steps' is prohibited

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I want to execute a reinforcement learning algorithm using an Atari environment emulation from gym package. This is part of the code of the algorithm, where I get the Attribute error in the title.

```
for t in range(int(args.max_timesteps)):

    episode_timesteps += 1

    # If generating the buffer, episode is low noise with p=low_noise_p.
    # If policy is low noise, we take random actions with p=eval_eps.
    # If the policy is high noise, we take random actions with p=rand_action_p.
    if args.generate_buffer:
        if not low_noise_ep and np.random.uniform(0,1) < args.rand_action_p - parameters["eval_eps"]:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
        else:
            action = policy.select_action(np.array(state), eval=True)

    if args.train_behavioral:
        if t < parameters["start_timesteps"]:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
        else:
            action = policy.select_action(np.array(state))

    # Perform action and log results
    next_state, reward, done, info, _ = env.step(action)
    episode_reward += reward

    # Only consider "done" if episode terminates due to failure condition
    done_float = float(done) if episode_timesteps < env._max_episode_steps else 0
    

    # For atari, info[0] = clipped reward, info[1] = done_float
    if is_atari:
        reward = info[0]
        done_float = info[1]
        
    # Store data in replay buffer
    replay_buffer.add(state, action, next_state, reward, done_float, done, episode_start)
    state = copy.copy(next_state)
    episode_start = False
```

The problem lies in "done_float = float(done) if episode_timesteps <env._max_episode_steps else 0".

How can I solve this problem???

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a script developed for older gym version.

Try to install gym 0.19.0 it by running:

```
pip install gym==0.19.0
```

Tell me if it did the job.